# Excel - overlapping cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010, display

We've encountered this wierd issue. Excel displays the values as overlapping. (screenshot below in link)
This looks not like a problem with wrapping text.
The issue appears when an Excel-file is send from one computer to another.

Below some findings/tests:

- Source computer: Excel 2016 , screenresolution (3840 x .....)
- Computer 1: Excel 2016, screenresolution 1920 x 1080 => OK
- Computer 2: Excel 2010, screenresolution unknown => OK
- Computer 3: Excel 2010, screenresolution 1600 x 900 => NOT OK
- Computer 4: Excel 2010, screenresolution 1600 x 900 => NOT OK
- This issue appears not only in read-only mode but also in editing
  mode.

Anyone some ideas why this issue is appearing?
Temp solution is to change the row height for every row.

http://imagebucket.net/ekn59axe0zgr/2016-09-30_17_09_13-Clipboard.jpg

Comment: I missed it. What am I expected to notice there? Are  you saying that the text seems to be floating towards the top of the line?

Comment: @blackpen Yes, indeed. If we change the row height the text is displayed properly.

Comment: I don't have excel handly with me right now. You could look for default font style, default template (if it is configured to align text with top of the row) for the particular excel installation (and for that particular version of excel). I wouldn't be surprised if excel right-justfies or top-justifies fonts depending on your locale.

Comment: Ok. I guess some kind of alignment compromise when the light height is not sufficient I guess. May be that installation of excel has become configured with low value of line height.